# How can I find minimum value for this inequality?

Tags: r

```
n <- 100
r <- rnorm(n, 0.5, 0.01)
xbar <- mean(r) 
mu <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, by=0.0001) 
F.mu <- function(xbar, mu) {   
          hstar <- xbar * log(xbar/mu) + (1-xbar) * log((1-xbar)/(1-mu))   
          ifelse(xbar >= mu, 1, exp(-n*hstar)) 
        }
```

Then I want to find the minimum value which satisfies F.mu > 0.05.

Comment: It takes more than one input. What are you minimizing with respect to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
x <- F.mu(xbar, mu)
mu[which(x == min(x[x > 0.05]))]
# 0.6211
```

Answer (score 1):

You could run your function with former specified values, then take the minimum of all > 0.05.

```
set.seed(927254)  # to make results comparable
n <- 100
r <- rnorm(n, 0.5, 0.01)
xbar <- mean(r) 
mu <- seq(from=0.0, to=1, by=0.0001) 

F.mu <- function(xbar.=xbar, mu.=mu){   
  hstar <-xbar*log(xbar/mu)+(1-xbar)*log((1-xbar)/(1-mu))   
  ifelse(xbar >= mu,1, exp(-n*hstar)) }

min(F.mu()[F.mu()>0.05])
# [1] 0.05018463
```